Running os on m.2 nvme plus retropie on external drive
I'm running raspberry pi os on a m.2 NVMe drive inside the case, but I'm wanting to run retropie on a NVMe external usb drive, is it possible to switch between drives? And if so how can I do that? I'm very new to the raspberry pi family so I'm still learning.
Many thanks
